# SQLite Joining tables on Android

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite

I want to join two tables in the same database. But any JOIN makes the work.

Example:

```
table1: date | name |surname

table2: date | brand
```

And I want a table:

table3:

```
date      |name |surname |brand

 01/01/13 jhon   who   null
 02/01/13 null   null  BMW
```

Where the rows are ordered by date but not joined, which means that some parameters will be null.But that's not a problem.

Is that possible? How?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [UNION ALL](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#compound) to get records from the respective source tables:

```
CREATE TABLE table3 AS
SELECT date, name, surname, NULL as brand FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT date, NULL, NULL, brand FROM table2
ORDER BY date
```

Comment: It do his job perfectly. I will use without create table statement. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Or just:

```
SELECT date, name, surname, NULL as brand FROM table1
UNION
SELECT date, NULL, NULL, brand FROM table2
```